# Error while pushing Flask app to heroku: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: git, flask, heroku, python-3.7, ubuntu-20.04

i am getting this error while pushing my Flask app to heroku:
**Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
remote: Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.** I've tried this command  `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` as someone suggested in another question and then i tried to install `PyGObject` using `pip3 install PyGObject` but i says that **requirements are already satisfied**

**Full Error**

```
remote:        Failed to build dbus-python PyGObject
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to safe-meadow-87431.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/safe-meadow-87431.git
```

Any help would be Appreciated. I am using `Ubuntu 20.04 "focal-fossa"` and python `version 3.7.5`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when pushing my app to Heroku - it got stuck on Pandas. For me the solution was to adjust the python version in my runtime.txt

From    `python-3.9.2`

to `python-3.8.8`